# Code Malfunction in Head.phtml file for Magento

Tags: php, wordpress, magento, magento-1.7

I integrated WP into Magento. When I go to add WP Recent posts code on the CMS home page of a static block. There was an error in the code. I found the Code is in **header.phtml**

The code :

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="<?php echo $this->getContentType() ?>" />
```

even when I edit it, it malfunctions to **getContentType() ?>" />**
You can see this error on every page of the site.
My website is:

```
        http://www.yourvaporizers.com
```

I just need some help for this. I know I can edit it with :

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
```

But I'd like to know what went wrong.

Update: More details

Extension I installed earlier, problem didn't occur until I put a WP block code on home page.

http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/msemantic-semantic-seo-for-rich-snippets-in-google-and-yahoo.html

Here is what I did. I changed my DOC type to this:

```
<?php echo '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>'; ?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML+RDFa 1.0//EN" "http://www.w3.org/MarkUp/DTD/xhtml-rdfa-1.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"  version="XHTML+RDFa 1.0"  xml:lang="<?php echo $this->getLang() ?>">
```

The old DOCTYPE code was this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="<?php echo $this->getLang() ?>" lang="<?php echo $this->getLang() ?>">
```

figured out the problem. It was in the code I had copied onto my DOC header.

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"  version="XHTML+RDFa 1.0"  xml:lang="<?php echo $this->getLang() ?>">
```

I deleted "> and it worked now!

### HOWEVER, My title tag isn't showing now. What should I do?

Answer (score 0):

I can see it too on your site (nice website). Of course the syntax in your question is correct so the direct output is mysterious. I suggest you confirm that `$this` has context and is not `null` and that, in context, `$this->getContentType() == 'text/html; charset=utf-8'` (var_dump() will expose that) and you might want to move to a stricter syntax along the lines of:

```
<?php
  echo ("<meta http-equiv=\"Content-Type\" content=\"".$this->getContentType()."\" />");
?>
```

**EDIT

Update following comments and more information

I am sorry my code broke your site.

I think you are chasing a typing error somewhere in your code. In fact I am certain of it because removing that ">" doesn't seem right either.

Can you add to your question the full code that is outputting the header? Maybe someone here can help spot the typing error.

Comment: That new code completely shuts down my site.  I changed it back to the default code.  Could it be I was changing the DOCtypes cause I was implementing  an extension. For SEO semantics.     Check the main question again, I put more details.